# Convert string to List of dates in flutter

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart, datetime

I have String :

```
String datesString= "[2022-04-14 15:51:10,2022-01-29 15:51:10]";
```

I need to convert it to list of DateTime or String ....

I try JsonDecode

```
List datesList= jsonDecode(datesString);
```

it throw a format exception :

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at
> character 6)
>
> [2022-04-14 15:51:10,2022-01-29 15:51:10]

how I can get the list from the String ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = datesString.toString().replaceAll("]", "").replaceAll("[", "");
List datesList = date.split(",");
```

List will be datesList

or you can do like this

```
 datesString = datesString.substring(1, datesString.length - 1);
List datesList = datesString.split(",");
```

Comment: i usually work with jsonDecode in this cases , your solution work fine thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

That string is not JSON.

```
final dates = datesString.substring(1, datesString.length - 1)
  .split(',')
  .map((date) => DateTime.parse(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of Strings :

```
datesString = datesString.substring( 1, datesString.length - 1);  
var list = datesString.split(",");
```

And to get a list of DateTimes, add to the above :

```
var listDates = [];
  
for (var i in list){
  listDates.add(DateTime.parse(i));
}
```